# How to extract first occurance of the data within the delimiter based on keyvalues?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Items   Data
enst.35 abc|frame|gtk|enst.24|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.23|pix|hoxg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
enst.18 abc|frame|gtk|enst.15|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk2|enst.59|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|holg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
enst.98 abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.45|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.74|pig|ho6g|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
enst.63 abc|frame|gtk|enst.34|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.67|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.39|pik|horg|,abc|framex|
```

I want to extract `Data` based on the `Items` value within the frame and extract only that data with in the separators (,). I want to match row1 value of col1 to row1 of col2. Similarly, row2 of col1 to row2 of col2....

If match is not found fill with 'NA' in the output columns. There can be multiple occurance of id in the same column, but I want to consider only the first occurrence.

The expected output is:

```
abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
NA
```

I tried follwing code to generate the output:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_table('file1.txt', sep="\t")
keywords=df['Items'].to_list()
df_map=df.Data[df.Data.str.contains('|'.join(as_list))].reindex(df.index)
```

But the output generated has all the terms containing the keywords:

```
Data
abc|frame|gtk|enst.24|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.23|pix|hoxg|abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.15|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk2|enst.59|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|holg|abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.45|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.74|pig|ho6g|abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
NA
```

What are the possible changes I can make in the code to generate correct ouput as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along the `axis=1` and apply the custom function which extracts the string associated with the occurrence of `df['Items']` in `df['Data']`:

```
import re

def find(s):
    mobj = re.search(rf"[^,]+{re.escape(s['Items'])}[^,]+", s['Data'])
    if mobj:
        return mobj.group(0)
    return np.nan

df['Data'] = df.apply(find, axis=1)
```

OR, Use a more faster solution:

```
pattern = '|'.join([rf'[^,]+{re.escape(k)}[^,]+'for k in df['Items']])
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.findall(pattern).str.get(0)
```

---

```
# print(df['Data'])

0    abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
1     abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|holg|
2        abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
3                                 NaN
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

we can formally define a key-value pair list as follows:

```
kvlist = <key>[kvdelim]<value>([pairdelim]<key>[kvdelim]<value>)*
key = <string>|<quoter><string><quoter>
value = <string>|<quoter><string><quoter>
quoter = "
```

Comment: I am not an expert coder. Can you make corresponding changes in my code and generate output as required